# Is this story about how Michael Dorn became Worf true?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actors, production

I once was told a story about how Michael Dorn auditioned for the role of Commander Worf on *Star Trek*. Instead of saying what the script he was given said, he tried to "act" like a Klingon would.

When it was his turn to audition, he put on his meanest face, stomped into the room, roared at the director, smashed the script on the table and stormed off again, unimpressed by anyone. After he left, the director then exclaimed "That's a Klingon!! I want him as Worf!"

However, I can't find any evidence about this story and whether or not it is true. I'm looking for a source to prove or disprove this story (even though the story is pretty great and fits the role of Worf).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### He did try to act like a Klingon, but he also read his lines.

From [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf#Origins_and_early_development), with a citation to *Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion*, 2nd edition, p. 20:

> Michael Dorn recalled his audition as follows: "I did not wear makeup, but I took on the psychological guise of a Klingon. I walked into Paramount in character. No jokes. No laughing with the other actors. I sat by myself waiting for my interview. When my turn came, I walked in, didn't smile, did the reading, thanked them, and walked right out."

Comment: Alright, that sounds like the story i was told was... embellished a bit ^^

Comment: @AlexanderMills - yeah, but yours is better.

Comment: I wonder where Michael got the impression that that's how Klingons are. In TOS they laughed and caroused. In fact, Worf is the only Klingon that seems to have problems with that.

Comment: @Xantec Excellent point. Maybe he was confused and thought he was auditioning for a Vulcan?

Comment: "...thanked them..." Yet he still got the part???  I've seen Klingons laugh, but I've never seen them thank anyone.

Comment: @Xantec They did in TNG era, too. Worf is the exception, with the intention that this is largely due to his separation from his race. Guinan even comments on it. So perhaps it's not so much that he acted "Klingon" as much as he acted like a Klingon sullen from living with humans too long. ;)

Comment: @Xantec *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock* prominently featured Klingons that are closer to what they became in TNG. That came out in 1984 and TNG premiered in 1987. It's quite likely that Michael Dorn based his characterization off of what was then the most recent portrayal of Klingons.

Comment: I always got the impression that Worf was trying live up to his Klingon heritage and his Federation upbringing and the same time. The hair-trigger temper and violent carousing part of "being Klingon" was not acceptable in the Federation, but the "proud, honourable warrior" part was, so that is what he went with.